# Count operation with parameters with mongodb ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

I was trying to use the count() Mongodb feature (db.collection_name.count({data:value}) using the Ruby Driver. I tried using de collection.count method, but it don't accept any parameters.

I checked the collection.count() method docs, it only returns the total amount of objects in the collection, where is no way you can pass a "filter" parameter to this method.

Is it possible use the count() Mongodb feature with filter parameters in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible use the count() Mongodb feature with filter parameters in some other way?

From the shell (command-line), you can do the following:

`db.collection.find({ data : value}).count()`

Obviously, you'll have to do something similar with Ruby, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: No, from shell I dont need to use find() then count(), I can use count() with parameters.

Comment: I don`t want to drag all data to memory just to get the number of objects of a given query.

Comment: OK, the ".find()" method only returns a cursor, it doesn't return all of the data. When you do a count() it should cycle through the data without actually loading it and pushing it across the wire.

Answer (score 2):

For those who just want the answer using the ruby driver:

```
# actual number of records
DB["posts"].find({"author" => "john"}).to_a.length
=> 48
# *total* number of documents in the collection (the query matching is ignored)
DB["posts"].count({"author" => "john"})
=> 1431
# more efficient way (using the count server-side command)
DB["posts"].find({"author" => "john"}).count
=> 1431
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to use `.count()` as you do on the command line, it's just poorly documented.

Mongo command line:

`db.User.find({"emails.5": {"$exists": true}}).count()`

Mongo Ruby driver:

`db.collection('User').count({:query => {"emails.5" => {"$exists" => true}}})`

This and other `.count()` options are document [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/1.x-stable/lib/mongo/collection.rb#L1064).